# sum() not working on lists of Timedelta objects

Tags: python, pandas, sum, timedelta

I have a list of `pandas.Timedelta` objects

```
In [31]: r
Out[31]: [Timedelta('0 days 00:00:12'), Timedelta('0 days 00:10:02')]
```

I can sum them up with the plus operator

```
In [32]: r[0] + r[1]
Out[32]: Timedelta('0 days 00:10:14')
```

But not using `sum()`

```
In [33]: sum(r)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-1ab9ba54065b> in <module>
----> 1 sum(r)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Timedelta'
```

Is that expected? I would expect `sum()` to work in this case.
Is there a way to sum the `pandas.Timedelta` objects in the list without explicitly iterating over it?

Comment: @Erfan Nice trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function

> ```
> This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
> reject non-numeric types.
> ```

However, you can make it work by passing in a `start` value (which is integer 0 by default)

```
from datetime import timedelta
r = [timedelta(0), timedelta(days=1)]
sum(r, timedelta(0))
```

Comment: :) The built in `sum`, `min` and `max` all allow for a `default` or `start` value to deal with empty iterables - the start value is the reason why `sum([])` returns 0

Answer (score 2):

It makes more sense to use a pandas Series, since we are already use the pandas Timedelta:

```py
In [3]: s = pd.Series([Timedelta('0 days 00:00:12'), Timedelta('0 days 00:10:02')])

In [4]: s.sum()
Out[4]: Timedelta('0 days 00:10:14')
```